# #define on ios frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I am creating a set of frameworks to be split into different projects, and separate targets.

In these frameworks i have different configurations, for test data, stubbed data, etc.
I used #define to make sure that stubbed classes werent included in binaries, URL's, etc. as these would be done at compile time.

However now that i am splitting all this into frameworks, i realise that a framework will be compiled against a specific configuration.
Is this correct even with dynamic frameworks? 
If so what would be the solution to allow these configurations to be used?
Would the creation a script to link to different frameworks to different configurations at what stage should this happen is it possible to link frameworks through scripts inside xcode?

At the moment i solved this issue by having nested projects inside, where it would require configurations to be changed. But I am not happy about this solution.
I wonder if there would be a more universal solution to this problem.
Any help would be really appreciated.